# C++, Time Functions (Linux) - Nanosecond Resolution

Tags: c++, linux, time, raspberry-pi, timedelay

As far as I know, "time-functions" are usually platform dependent. I am using a Raspberry-Pi, so my OS is Raspbian, or Debian, (linux).

First I should explain *why* it is critical that I can delay a program's execution, as accurately as possible, to the 10's of nanoseconds precision level. I am interfacing to an ADC (Analog-to-Digital Converter). It is important that the ADC has time to send logic signals HIGH or LOW once instructions have been sent to the device.

For example:

One data line controls the "conversion-request" pin. This pin must go logic low for 20 ns to start a conversion request.

Another example is the "read-request" pin. This data line must go logic low for 10 ns to enable data on the output bus.

Currently I have a program which is structured like this: (Using the wiringPi libraries.)

```
return_type functionName()
{
    digitalWrite(CONVERT_RQ, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1); // Part of the wiringPi.h library
    digitalWrite(CONVERT_RQ, HIGH);
}
```

I don't think it is safe to remove the `delayMicroseconds(1);` call, as the ADC could miss the logic low pulse. (From `digitalWrite`.) I think the pins can switch between high and low at about 200 kHz - not sure about that though. EDIT: I mean MHz

Delaying for 1 microsecond is obviously pretty wasteful. I would like to wait for 1 % of that time, ideally.

As far as I know, the delayMicroseconds() function actually suspends the program, and the OS switches to running another task while it waits. This also isn't ideal, as we might end up waiting for 2 microseconds, perhaps longer. Switching back to another process would be pointless for less than 1 microsecond of course. Wouldn't get much done in that time.

Anyone got any ideas about how this might be done?
Thanks

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: :) You seem to need some completely different hardware with completely different software.

Comment: @V-X Yeah I've thought that many times... Everything else is too expensive though

Comment: You need a hardware chip, which will do only this task in real time, otherwise the multithread system will try to switch to something else and you'll never be able to

Comment: Actually, according to this https://projects.drogon.net/accurate-delays-on-the-raspberry-pi/ wiringPi is already using a busy/wait loop with timer polling on short delays. So there is no OS switching overhead.

Comment: or try a real time distribution like http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=49373 or http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/is-it-possible-to-run-real-time-software

Comment: On the Pi's CPU, 20ns is only about 10 cycles. It's HIGHLY unlikely that any signal that comes from the OS layer is going to get anywhere near that fine of a resolution. Microsecond resolution is probably about the best you can expect from a CPU with that low of a clockspeed running a full OS layer, without some form of special function unit hardware specifically designed for the purpose.

Comment: ... I guess I could `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++);` and put that in my function `crude_delay()` - and adjust 1000 using a scope?

Comment: You're still going to run into all sorts of timing variances. Seriously, the Pi isn't meant for bit-banging high-speed low-level hardware interfaces from userland. Generally the SOP is to have some form of ATMega/PIC doing the high-speed real-time GPIO and then communicate to that via the Pi's USART.

Comment: @aruisdante Thanks for the response, none of the Arduino like boards I know about are fast enough for this purpose though. Those are the only systems which I know how to use really.

Comment: How fast is the ADC you're trying to use?

Comment: @EdwardBird you may consider using FPGA together with Raspberry PI to interact with ADC

Comment: How about a simple CMOS multivibrator clock circuit, external to the PI, for the timing the ADC?  Should be only a few dollars in parts.  Then, just program the PI to read the inputs from the ADC in a loop, and this way, each iteration it will get current data from the ADC.

Comment: -1. The question starts out with the assumption that this is done in a _program_ while the only reasonable way to do this in software is from a device driver.

Comment: So why is that a -1 vote then?

Comment: @MSalters It might be more helpful if you explain how to write a device driver, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a C++11 compliant compiler, you could check out [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)'s high_resolution_clock and do a busy-wait.

I don't know how delayMicroseconds is implemented, but if you are infact sleeping the program you have very little control over when your process is reawaken. Also know that your process may be put to sleep anyhow once the OS "ticks" in to schedule work.

Comment: OS context-switching resolution is usually in the ten-microsecond range. No chance the OP can do this in userland.